# Transition from "MacPython" to MacPorts python3 a good idea for EIN & Scipy?

Tags: emacs, python-3.x, scipy, macports, jupyter-notebook

I started off learning Python on OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) with a python.org [Python dmg](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/python-3.3.0-macosx10.6.dmg). I think [I've seen this called "MacPython" on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213690/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-to-install-python-modules-on-a-mac/7220022#7220022), but I'm also thinking that [this MacPython](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jack/macpython/index.html) (currently Google's top hit for "MacPython") is different, right?

Although I felt like my python.org Python 3.3.0 install was working reasonably well for me initially (using `distribute`, `easy_install`, and `pip`, I installed several new packages including `IPython`), I'd like to start using [Emacs IPython Notebook (EIN)](http://tkf.github.com/emacs-ipython-notebook/) and [Scipy](http://scipy.github.com/install.html), and it's clear to me that this kind of arrangement is going to require a lot of additional stuff from the [CheeseShop](http://pypi.python.org/pypi). Plus, I've been very happily using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) for GNU Emacs and other unix (non-Python) packages for a long time, so I'm thinking that it might be a good idea to move all my Python work (I'm focused on learning py3) away from what I have now with the python.org install and into MacPorts Python.

Is that a good idea? IOW, am I likely to be making for a great deal of extra time/work/headache for myself (like the headaches that @davidavr writes about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189912/what-package-manager-do-you-prefer-for-mac-os-x) when he writes, "MacPorts would pull down and install the full Python 2.4 distro along with the library.") for very little gain or is the benefit of using a package manager like MacPorts for my Python stuff going to be a big timesaver like I suspect it might be?

I've read many other threads here ([most rather old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213690/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-to-install-python-modules-on-a-mac/7220022#7220022)) that partly relate, but don't feel like there's anything recent that really addresses my question, and I encountered lots of older advice where it was clear that newer advice conflicted, so I'm asking what may be considered a duplicate, but if it is, I can't help thinking that the passage of several years may have changed some of the answers to older similar questions.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, but at a guess: it will be slow to set up, because it's compiling a lot of stuff from scratch, but there are a lot of benefits to having a serious package manager dealing with installing stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying with MacPorts and pip3 for many days and ultimately being unable to get a functional IPython notebook/qtconsole going with matplotlib and numpy and sympy and all that wonderful stuff, I gave up and switched to homebrew which ultimately worked for me, but I had to do a regular install from source for several of the bigger packages. Although homebrew would install these packages, it seemed to be doing so strictly for Python 2.7 and never for Python3; I tried several options in homebrew to fix this, but finally gave up and just installed from source for those difficult packages like Qt.

So I guess my experience was that MacPorts with pip3 was not a good idea for my particular goal whereas homebrew with pip3 was better, but still incomplete for Scipy packages with Python3. (Although perhaps if I had tried installing from source to supplement MacPorts the way I did with homebrew then MacPorts would have sufficed also.)

Looking back on the experience, I think there is a great need for more detailed and comprehensive documentation for new users on how to start from scratch and build these capabilities because I tried many different strategies and it was ultimately only through trial and error and lots of different bits and pieces of advice from all over the web that I finally got some of it going. I still don't have EIN going, but I think that's going to require tools strictly from the emacs world to get that going. EIN documentation strongly encourages use of an emacs package manager called el-get (or MELPA), and I found both to be buggy, so all I have thus far is IPython notebook using a browser which is still wonderful.

**EDIT**

Oh, one other very important thing: I stopped trying with Python 3.3.0 and moved back to Python 3.2.3 as [numpy 1.6.2 doesn't support Python 3.3.0 and although this has apparently been fixed in numpy 1.7.x, there are currently no plans to release a numpy 1.6.3](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/2221).