# Jupyter notebook wont show image with matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot image using jupyter notebook.

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
Z=np.array(((1,2,3,4,5),(4,5,6,7,8),(7,8,9,10,11)))
im = plt.imshow(Z, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

And I get some strange error.
When I ran same code in Pycharm, It worked but wont work in jupyter notebook.
.[image]

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817940/matplotlib-and-libpng-issues-with-ipython-notebook

Comment: Yeah Solved...
Thanks man

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib and libpng issues with ipython notebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817940/matplotlib-and-libpng-issues-with-ipython-notebook)